# Programa tem lixo de memória 2 em C

Tags: c, struct

Essa é a pergunta do programa:

Faça um programa, utilizando a função abaixo, que exiba o maior salário de cada departamento de uma
empresa e quantos funcionários ganham o maior salário do departamento. Para cada departamento, o
programa deverá ler o código do departamento e a quantidade de funcionários, e para cada
funcionário, a matrícula e o salário. Término da leitura dos departamentos: código do departamento =
0.
Faça a função um_departamento para processar os funcionários de um departamento. Esta função
deverá receber como parâmetro a quantidade de funcionários do departamento, ler os dados de cada
funcionário, descobrir o maior salário do departamento e quantos funcionários ganham este maior
salário, armazenando-os nas variáveis cujos endereços são fornecidos na chamada da função.

Eu realizei o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct funcionario
{
    char nome[20];
    float salario;
    char matricula[10];
};

void um_departamento(struct funcionario *func, int *numfunc){
    int i, maior,cont=0;
    maior = func[0].salario;;

    for (i = 0; i < *numfunc; i++){

        if (func[i].salario > maior){
            maior = func[i].salario;
            cont++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d", maior,cont);

}

int main(){
    int departamento, i, functot, coddep, depzin,num=20;
    struct funcionario funz[num];

    printf ("Digite o departamento e seu codigo");
    scanf ("%d %d", &departamento, &coddep);

    for (i = 0; i < departamento; i++){
        dep (functot);
        print ("Digite a matricula e o salário");
        scanf ("%f%f", &funz[i].salario, &funz[i].matricula);




    }

    um_departamento(funz, &num);

    return 0;

}
```

Como eu posso arrumá-lo?
Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: sobre lixo de memoria pesquise um pouco sobre o comando fflush(stdin); mas e basicamente colocar esse comando antes de leitura de dados.

Answer (score 2):

Matheus, beleza? \o/

Então, o seu código tem alguns erros de sintaxe que prejudicam a lógica implementada. Vou listá-los:

i. Uso inadequado do caractere ponto e vírgula

```
maior = func[0].salario;;
```

ii. Chamada de uma função que não foi criada, com uso de argumento sem valor

```
dep (functot);
```

iii. Leitura de um float para uma variável do tipo char (funz.matricula)

```
scanf ("%f%f", &funz[i].salario, &funz[i].matricula);
```

Calma. Esses tipos de erros acontecem e são comuns para quem está iniciando na programação. Eu vi que você se esforçou bastante, mas creio que não tenha compreendido completamente o que solicitava a questão e acabou implementando uma lógica um pouco confusa. Vamos lá:

1. Na função *um_departamento*, você deve realizar a leitura dos dados dos funcionários e não somente verificar qual é o maior salário do departamento;
2. Ainda para essa função, você deve verificar quantos funcionários recebem salário exatamente igual ao maior salário do departamento. Assim, a sua variável *cont* não está sendo bem utilizada;
3. Na *main*, você deve realizar a leitura dos departamentos enquanto o valor fornecido para o código do departamento for diferente de 0;
4. Para cada departamento válido (*cod_dep* != 0), serão realizadas as leituras das informações do total de funcionários. Essas informações abrangem a matricula e o salario. Assim, o campo nome na estrutura funcionario é desnecessário.

Uma perguntinha, futuro programador: **você considera viável utilizar vetor para a resolução do problema?** Bem, vetores não são estruturas flexíveis e são mais recomendados em contextos nos quais temos noção do total exato de elementos necessários - o que não é o nosso caso, já que estamos trabalhando com uma quantidade não definida de departamentos. Então, o que você acha de trocar o uso de vetores por listas encadeadas? Será beeeem menos trabalhoso e muito mais compreensível, pois te permitirá definir cada elemento da lista como um departamento, com seu código e uma quantidade X de funcionários definidos. Ah, para os funcionários, você pode sim utilizar um vetor de estruturas. Será fácil de implementar.

Vou compartilhar as estruturas que irão te ajudar na resolução. Tome elas como base para a sua implementação.

```
struct listaDepts
{
    int cod_dep;
    struct funcionario *f;
    struct listaDepts *prox;
};
typedef struct listaDepts ListaDepts;

struct funcionario
{
    char matricula[10];
    float salario;
};
typedef struct funcionario Funcionario;
```

Qualquer coisa, se não conseguir ou sentir dificuldades, pode entrar em contato comigo que será um prazer ajudá-lo.

Um abraço! =]

Comment: Fala, tudo bem?
Então, eu entendi o que você quis dizer. Estou bastante confuso ainda em questão de como usar ponteiro e structs. Por eu estar ainda caminhando na programação, não faz sentido algum usar ponteiros e structs em um exercício e fiz por tentar mesmo.
A questão é: como poderia melhorar meu aprendizado em C com relação aos ponteiros e structs/Vetores? Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: Fala, Matheus. Tudo em paz aqui, e com você? Perdão pela resposta tardia... O uso de ponteiros e structs é algo extremamente comum na programação e caracteriza o que de fato vem a ser as estruturas de dados. Como foi apontado na resposta, é possível simplificar a resolução do problema fazendo uso de listas encadeadas. De forma resumida e direta, listas encadeadas são uma sequência de structs que armazenam dois tipos de dados: a informação e um ponteiro para o próximo elemento. Analise a estrutura ListaDepts e identifique-os. Note que o ponteiro f apontará para o vetor de funcionários do dept.

Comment: Prosseguindo: o ponteiro *prox sempre apontará para o próximo elemento da lista, que será um struct do tipo ListaDepts com um ponteiro para o vetor de funcionários e um ponteiro para o próximo elemento da lista. Qual a vantagem de se trabalhar com listas? No problema citado por você, não temos noção da quantidade de departamentos a serem fornecidos - assim, o uso de uma estrutura não flexível, que é o vetor, torna a resolução complexa. Com o uso de listas, a resolução é simplificada, pois cada elemento será criado a medida que for fornecido um novo departamento. Ou seja, podemos ter N depts.

Comment: Vejo que esses conceitos são novos para você. De início, podem até parecer complexos demais, assim como foram para mim. Então, vou lhe recomendar uma apostila que demonstra de forma simplificada e didática as principais estruturas de dados utilizadas na programação. Creio que será de grande valia para você!

Link: https://goo.gl/1rcmdY